# ADB screenrecord command not found

Tags: android, adb

I am unable to run `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/my.mp4`

Device specification that i am trying to run this command:

- Honor 5C
- Android 6.0

whenever i run the screenrecord command it shows command not found.

```
D:\adb>adb shell screenrecord
/systerm/bin/sh:screenrecord not found
```

Also i have builtin screen record application is this reason for my issue?
Is there any other way to capture screen except screencap?
Or can i tap into builtin screen record application?
Any suggestions or idea are appreciable.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried other adb shell commands and did they work? Does `adb screencap` work? I do find it odd that you were able to do screenrecord  on other devices but not this particular one. Just want to make sure its not something dumb like not authorizing your PC for developer mode from the Honor 5C.

Comment: screencap works fine in Honor 5C device i am able to take screenshot from that command. but unable to find command screenrecord , i have feeling that it is because of builtin screen recorder i am facing this issue but not sure about this. @Morrison Chang

Comment: I get the same thing on a Huawei P9 Lite. It also has a built-in screen video recorder.

Answer (score 11):

Huawei has removed this cmd tool from /system/bin. Run command `adb shell ls /system/bin/` see if you can find this tool from the outputs

Comment: Correct - Huawei has removed this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have copied this line from command line, then it seems to be spelling-error:

`adb shell screenrecord /sdacrd/my.mp4`

Should it not be like `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/my.mp4` ?

Are you trying to save this video on your device or on your PC?

Now, to record screen or to capture screenshot, I strongly recommend to use Android Studio as it has inbuilt options to record.

It's here in MacOS:
[image]

Comment: I updated my question that was typo error, I entered adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/my.mp4 though i am getting error. For other devices it is working fine for me. i dont want to do it in android studio i want it in ADB itself. @Prashant Saini

Comment: Does your device has given permissions to app to External Storage ?

Comment: Yeah i am able to run this  adb shell screencap /sdcard/a.png and can see a.png file.

Comment: Can you try running this command `adb shell screenrecord /mnt/sdcard/my.mp4 `

Comment: Nope :-( did't worked for me i got the same error again  **/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found**

Comment: Then I will really suggest you to use Android Studio at least to confirm that whether your Honor device supports screen-recording or does it have that screenrecord command or not??

Comment: On Studio, if the Video Recording button is disabled, then it means your device doesn't support it. You'll then have to find out another ways.

Comment: in android studio i am only able to take screenshot recording button is disabled

Comment: You have any idea how my builtin screen recorder works if my mobile does't support screenrecord.

Comment: If Studio button is disabled, then looks like your phone doesn't support video recording via debugging bridge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to undestand whe does `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/my.mp4` mean. It means execution "screenrecord" command in your phone's shell. You could do the same by installing any terminal emulator on your phone, run it and type (on phone) `screenrecord /sdcard/my.mp4`

You are getting "command not found" error, it means there is no "screenrecord" command available. Most devices should have it included, but it seems your device have it missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to capture screen except screencap?

**In one word**: [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrcpy):

> scrcpy is a free and open-source screen mirroring application that allows control of an Android device from a Windows, macOS, or Linux desktop computer. The software is developed by Genymobile, which also developed Genymotion, an Android emulator.

On their [Github repository](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) you will find instructions to install it on several operating systems (including Windows, Linux, MacOS) and to run it, with various options to set resolution, bitrate, screen orientation, etc.

Unless you explicitly disable this feature, it also lets you control your device from the PC.

Using the `--record` option you can save the screen capture on a video, and using the `--crop` option you can even capture or record only a specific part of the screen.

After a long search, this is the tool I liked the most and that I am using, since there is no `screenrecord` in my phone.