# How to mirror phone screen using ADB Sideload?

Tags: android, adb, rsa, usb-debugging

**Information:**

- Windows: 10
- Smartphone: Alcatel Pixi 4 5" 5045J (Rooted)
- ADB version: 1.0.39
- USB debugging is enabled.

**Problem:**

The screen to my phone is damaged and ring does not work. I would
   like to mirror the phone screen on the PC, but I could not. Informs
   that the dialogue must be confirmed:

[Image - Allow USB debugging?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqRVT.jpg)
I can not confirm this. The screen touch does not work, neither does the mouse. Only the side keys of the phone work

**Questions:**

- Using the phone's recovery mode, would it be possible to mirror the
  Android screen on the PC?
- Can I use Sideload to allow  USB debugging access to ADB? To not need to confirm the dialog.
- Do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61781824/6854564) ...

Answer (score 2):

Use following command to mirror your device on computer using ADB

```
adb shell "while true; do screenrecord --output-format=h264 -; done" | ffplay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video -
```

More info can be found here : https://knowitlabs.no/mirroring-your-android-display-to-mac-or-linux-20b2a7043f85

Comment: Perhaps this answer requires more info? All I get is sh: screenrecord: not found